# How are characterstic polynomials (resp. Alexander polynomials) distributed amongst adjacency matrices (resp. grid diagrams)?

Tags: knot-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Fix $n$, and consider the characteristic polynomials for all $C=2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ adjacency matrices representing undirected, unweighted graphs on $n$ vertices.

> Are the characteristic polynomials distributed somewhat uniformly among adjacency matrices?  Or are some characteristic polynomials "much more popular" than others?  If so, is there some Zipf-law distribution?

The work of [Andries Brouwer](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/cospectral/cospectralA.html) counts the number of characteristic polynomials for smallish $n$ relative to the number of *graphs*.

---

Similarly fix $n$, and consider the Alexander polynomials associated with the $C=n!\times \lfloor{\frac{n!}{e}}\rfloor$ [grid diagrams](https://picturethismaths.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/grid-diagrams-for-knots/) that represent various links/knots.

> Are the Alexander polynomials distributed somewhat uniformly among the grid diagrams?

The work of [Canterralla, Chapman, and Mastin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05749) suggests that a Zipf-like law tends to apply for random knot diagrams - some knot types are more popular than others.  I suspect that there are more grid diagrams that have an Alexander polynomial associated with, say, $7_6$ than with $7_1$, because the symmetries of $7_1$ make it harder to be randomly generated.  But if $n$ were large enough, maybe uniformity takes over.

---

My motivation considers a uniform superposition $\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}|A \rangle|B \rangle$ - $A$ being over adjacency matrices (grid diagrams) and $B$ being a characteristic polynomial (Alexander polynomial) of the respective adjacency matrix (grid diagram).  Over all $|A \rangle$, is $|B \rangle$ most likely uniformly distributed?  If I measure $|B\rangle$ will some polynomials be more likely than others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends quite nontrivially on which model of random knots you consider. For a general description, see Even-Zohar's [very nice survey.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10470) In many models a random knot is a very small knot (unknot, trefoil, figure eight dominating), with the resulting singularity of the distribution of Alexander polynomials.